# Histogram: increasing space between bars

Tags: tikz-pgf, bar-chart, histogram

How can I maintain the same width of the bars, and at the same time increasing the space that separates them?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}[p]
    \centering  
    \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\footnotesize]
        \begin{axis} [ylabel={Results},
            width=\textwidth,
            height=8cm,
            enlarge x limits=0.03,
            ybar,ymin=0,ymax=1750,xtick=data,
            ymajorgrids=true,xtick pos=left,
            ytick={0, 500, 1000, 1500},
            yticklabels={$0$,$500$,$1000$,$1500$},
            x tick label style=%
            {rotate=90,anchor=east},
            xticklabel interval boundaries,
            symbolic x coords={$1990$,$1991$,$1992$,$1993$,$1994$,$1995$,$1996$,$1997$,$1998$,$1999$,$2000$,$2001$,$2002$,$2003$,$2004$,$2005$,$2006$,$2007$,$2008$,$2009$,$2010$,$2011$,$2012$,$2013$,$2014$,$2015$,$2016$,$2017$,$2018$,$2019$,$2020$},
            ]
            \addplot
            [ybar interval, fill=cyan,
            draw=black] coordinates
            {($1990$, 31) ($1991$, 23) ($1992$, 36) ($1993$, 34) ($1994$, 46) ($1995$, 72) ($1996$, 127) ($1997$, 105) ($1998$, 137) ($1999$, 147) ($2000$, 135) ($2001$, 162) ($2002$, 211) ($2003$, 209) ($2004$, 301) ($2005$, 349) ($2006$, 452) ($2007$, 474) ($2008$, 635) ($2009$, 943) ($2010$, 998) ($2011$, 1047) ($2012$, 1069) ($2013$, 1173) ($2014$, 1236) ($2015$, 1106) ($2016$, 1236) ($2017$, 1329) ($2018$, 1447) ($2019$, 1697) ($2020$, 1291)
            };          
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I tried to add the `bar width=9pt,` and to eliminate `ybar interval,` but the space between bars seems to be different for some pairs of bars.

Comment: Hello S1m0n3, welcome to TeX.SE! Please make your code complete by adding the preamble with just the necessary packages and options to load this snippet as you see it, so we don't have to guess them (it can be hard to do lol). :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[x=4mm, height=8cm,
    ybar,
    bar width=3mm,
    enlarge x limits=0.02,          
    enlarge y limits={.1, upper},   
ymajorgrids=true,
    minor y tick num=4,   
    xtick=data,
    ytick={0, 500, 1000, 1500},
    yticklabels={0,500,1000,1500},
    x tick label style={rotate=90,anchor=east},
symbolic x coords={ 1990,1991,1992,1993,1994,
                    1995,1996,1997,1998,1999,
                    2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,
                    2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,
                    2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,
                    2015,2016,2017,2018,2019,
                    2020},
                    ]
\addplot coordinates   {(1990, 31)   (1991, 23)   (1992, 36)   (1993, 34)   (1994, 46)
                        (1995, 72)   (1996, 127)  (1997, 105)  (1998, 137)  (1999, 147)
                        (2000, 135)  (2001, 162)  (2002, 211)  (2003, 209)  (2004, 301)
                        (2005, 349)  (2006, 452)  (2007, 474)  (2008, 635)  (2009, 943)
                        (2010, 998)  (2011, 1047) (2012, 1069) (2013, 1173) (2014, 1236)
                        (2015, 1106) (2016, 1236) (2017, 1329) (2018, 1447) (2019, 1697)
                        (2020, 1291)
                       };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Miain difference between proposed solution and your MWE:

- defined distance between bars (`x=5mm`)
- defined bar's width (`bar width=3mm`)
- removed `ybar interval,` from `\addplot`

Comment: Yes thanks, but I obtain a similar result by adding `bar width=9pt` and eliminating  `ybar interval` and `xticklabel interval boundaries`. The problem (?) is that  I see different spaces between bars; is it just my impression?

Comment: @s1m0n3, all is about width of bars and distances between bar coordinates.  Distance between coordinates (in my MWE is determined by `x=5`) had to be greater than bar width (in my MWE `barwidth=3mm`).  Size of this length is on showed diagram on the end scaled so, that diagram has desired width, for example equal to `\textwidth`.